# How to structure div content horizontally with CSS

Tags: css

```html
<div class="landing page">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="title-container">
      <img src="https://mathbymiles.com/uploads/default/original/1X/aa6e06d5ee08fd78372a0aaeec676eac87ecf191.svg" alt="Picture" id="landing-picture">
    </div>
    <div class="text-container">
      <div class="text-contents">
        Welcome!
      </div>
    </div>
    <img>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to structure the content inside of my landing page so that I have two "columns" of content: the left content is `title-container` and the right-content is `text-container`. And I want to basically fill the page. The example that I'm looking at that I want to achieve is the landing page of codecademy.com, with the picture of the girl on the left and the sign-up form on the right. I tried to inspect with Chrome tools and I tried to look at some examples online, but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Lemme google that for you :) https://dev.to/drews256/ridiculously-easy-row-and-column-layouts-with-flexbox-1k01

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply use flexbox .

```
.container{
  display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As u did not provide information of what exactly is going wrong with your implementation and also don't share your CSS classes i can only guess solutions for your problem.

try set `title-container` and `text-container` to `display: inline-block` and `width: 50%`